# Pandas DataFrame - mixed date formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to analyse some covid data I pulled from a csv file available online - https://api.covid19india.org/csv/latest/tested_numbers_icmr_data.csv

I trimmed it down to only use the Tested As Of and Total Samples Tested columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("tested_numbers_icmr_data.csv")
df = tested[['Total Samples Tested', 'Tested As Of']]
```

Then renamed the date column, converted to datetime and set it as my index.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Tested As Of':'Date'})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

I printed the dataframe to check if everything was as intended and noticed that some of the date formatting was all mixed up.
Here is a snippet:

```
2020-10-04              161330.0
2020-11-04              179374.0
2020-12-04              195748.0
2020-04-13              217554.0
2020-04-14              244893.0
2020-04-15              274599.0
2020-04-16              302956.0
```

These kinds of inconsistencies are all over the dataframe. Is there a solution to this? Because of this mixed formatting some dates seem to be missing when in reality the formatting is plain wrong.

**UPDATE**: I checked the file manually and the entries are all correctly formatted and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

If the formatting of the dates in the original file are consistent, you can supply the "format" argument in the pd.to_datetime() function. It follows the same formatting rules as Python's datetime module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

So in your case might be pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d").

Comment: Just figured that out. Although, this is interesting, why does pd.to_datetime mess up without explicit formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was just missing a format statement

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```